# Nested Structures in IDA

Tags: ida, debugging, idapython, linux, hexrays

I'm trying to figure out how to explore structs in IDA, and getting stuck on the basics. I wrote a very basic test app;

```
int main() {
    const int kBits = 1024;
    const int kExp = 3;

    RSA *rsa = RSA_generate_key(kBits, kExp, 0, 0);
    RSA_print_fp(stdout, rsa, 0);

    RSA_free(rsa);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I imported the OpenSSL headers, so IDA now understands what `RSA*` and `BIGNUM*` are. `BIGNUM` is actually pointing to [`bignum_st`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/367ace6870e9cbc8fe21dff2ffe4673a98ea42f8/crypto/bn/bn_lcl.h#L218) which is referenced from RSA, which is [`rsa_st`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/39c44eee7fd89ce13e805873e1c43bd8e488a93f/crypto/rsa/rsa_locl.h#L28).

Then, dropped a breakpoint in the pseudocode view;
[image]

Now, if I hover over `v3`, I see it's parsing the struct. So I want to do something like grab the value of `rsa->d->dmax`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this? I can't seem to find a way to access `v3` by name in IDAPython, nor can I seem to 'walk' the structure to get to the int that lives at `dmax`. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Your code works as usual but it raises exception code in IDA+windbg. Can you share the compiled Windows binary?

Comment: Can I assume what you want to do is to dump the value of `v3->d->dmax` upon reaching this breakpoint?

Comment: @Pororo yes, exactly!

Comment: @Biswapriyo I can't imagine it would work in windows.. I'm doing this under Linux (CentOS 7 if it matters)

Comment: for some reason I thought this was the writing stack exchange, anyway -  +1 good question! will follow this.

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge of the IDAPython API isn't the most complete, but what I would do is

1. Read the source (or look in IDA) to find the location (byte offsets) of `d` in `rsa_st` and `dmax` in `bignum_st`. This is easy since the members of the structures above `d` and `dmax` are pointers or int types.
2. Inspect the disassembly just before the call and determine the location of `v3` -
   from the pseudocode it appears to be stored in the stack. If you are lucky, pressing tab while your cursor is on `v3` will take you to some mov operation in disassembly.
3. When the breakpoint is hit, use a combination of `idc.get_reg_value` and `idc.get_bytes` commands (see https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/162.shtml), using the result from step 2 as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Set breakpoint. Run the local debugger with <kbd>F9</kbd>. Open Debugger dropdown menu form menu bar and choose "Take memory snapshot". Here is the screenshot:

[image: Take_Memory_Snapshot]

2. Double click on the variables that you want to know (here the `RSA*` pointer). IDA will take you to the stack view (aka. IDA View-RIP). Do not move the cursor otherwise you will get different value. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to name the variable in that stack view. "Rename address" window will pop-up. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Enter_Variable_Name]

3. After naming the variable in that stack view, press <kbd>Y</kbd> to add the data type i.e. structure type. For this case it will be `RSA`, not the pointer because all stack variables placed linearly. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Enter_Data_type]

Now you can see all the struct members value.

Answer (score 0):

"Setting a breakpoint" suggests that you are doing dynamic analysis. Assuming that and assuming this happens on a real system, may I suggest an alternative route for Linux, based on my other assumption that you are linking OpenSSL dynamically?

When on Linux (and a number of other unixoid systems) you can guide [the dynamic linker/loader](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) to override a function. If you know Windows and DLLs it could probably be compared a little to DLL placement attacks, but it is more flexible and requires less effort.

NB: Obviously *this* approach doesn't teach you how about dealing with structs in IDA, but I think it is a very powerful technique to keep in mind. Because it is an alternative approach that doesn't satisfy your constraint of wanting to learn more about dealing with structs in IDA, I am making this a CW.

There are some components for this approach:

1. you need a "wrapper" shared object, let's call it `mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so`, exporting `RSA_generate_key()` with a binary compatible signature to that from the original OpenSSL shared object (something like `libcrypto.so`)
2. you need to tell `ld.so` via environment variable to preload `mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so` (see below)

`ld.so` will take care -- when resolving symbols -- that the preloaded ones take precedence. This is how one of the modes of operation [for eFence is implemented (look for `LD_PRELOAD`, the man page also lists the exported symbols)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/efence).

So now your only remaining task would be to turn up the correct prototype [for `RSA_generate_key`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_generate_key.html) from the `libcrypto.so` that your binary uses (try `ldd ./your_binary` to list dependencies) and write the wrapper `.so`, using [`dlopen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [`dlsym()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to locate the *original* `RSA_generate_key` symbols from the *actual* `libcrypto.so`

---

#### Full example

##### `main.c`

This is approximately the program you created and are analyzing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

int main(int argc, char const ** argv, char const** envp)
{
    int const kBits = 1024;
    int const kExp = 3;

    RSA *rsa = RSA_generate_key(kBits, kExp, 0, 0);
    RSA_print_fp(stdout, rsa, 0);

    RSA_free(rsa);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

##### `mock_openssl.c`

This is the wrapper shared object, which we'll load with `LD_PRELOAD`.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

typedef RSA* (*RSA_generate_key_t)(int, unsigned long, void (*)(int, int, void *), void *);
static RSA_generate_key_t real_RSA_generate_key = 0;
static void* libcrypto = 0;

static void init() __attribute__((constructor));
static void fini() __attribute__((destructor));

void init()
{
    if (!libcrypto)
    {
        libcrypto = dlopen("libcrypto.so.3", RTLD_NOW);
        if (!libcrypto)
        {
            libcrypto = dlopen("libcrypto.so", RTLD_NOW);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Loaded libcrypto: %p\n", libcrypto);
        if (libcrypto)
        {
            real_RSA_generate_key = (RSA_generate_key_t)dlsym(libcrypto, "RSA_generate_key");
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\tRSA_generate_key == %p\n", (void*)real_RSA_generate_key);
    }
}

void fini()
{
    if (libcrypto)
    {
        dlclose(libcrypto);
        libcrypto = 0;
        real_RSA_generate_key = 0;
    }
}

RSA* RSA_generate_key(int bits, unsigned long e, void (*callback)(int, int, void *), void *cb_arg)
{
    if (!real_RSA_generate_key)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "FATAL: Have no function pointer for original RSA_generate_key()\n");
        return 0;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Calling real_RSA_generate_key(%i, %lu, %p, %p)\n", bits, e, callback, cb_arg);
    RSA* ret = real_RSA_generate_key(bits, e, callback, cb_arg);
    /* do something with ret here */
    if (ret)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Returned RSA key: %p ... I can do what I want with it ... MUHAHAHA!\n", ret);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Explanation:

- `RSA_generate_key_t` parrots the prototype of the original function as `typedef`
- `real_RSA_generate_key` is going to hold the function pointer retrieved from the real `libcrypto.so`
- `libcrypto` is going to hold the handle to the loaded `libcrypto.so`
- `init()` -- declared as constructor -- will run when *our* wrapper `.so` gets loaded

  - it attempts to load `libcrypto.so.3`
  - failing that, attempts to load `libcrypto.so`
  - if successful in either of the preceding steps, it uses `dlsym()` to fetch the address of the real `RSA_generate_key` and stores it in `real_RSA_generate_key`
  - ... also outputs the steps, something like:

    ```
    Loaded libcrypto: 0x7f9ad86e3700
            RSA_generate_key == 0x7f9ad8478b50
    ```
- `finit()` -- declared as destructor -- will run when our wrapper `.so` gets unloaded
- `RSA_generate_key()` is our wrapper to the original function and will be called in place of the one from `libcrypto.so` by a program that preloads this `.so`

##### `GNUmakefile`

The GNU `make` recipes to build our stuff.

```
CC:=gcc
CFLAGS:=$(strip -Wno-deprecated-declarations $(CFLAGS))
all: bin so
bin: your_binary
so: mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so

bin: LDLIBS=-lcrypto

your_binary: main.c
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

so: CFLAGS=-shared -fPIC
so: LDFLAGS=-Wl,-soname,libcrypto.so
so: LDLIBS=-ldl

mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so: mock_openssl.c
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

.PHONY: all so bin
```

##### Steps

1. write each of the above with the name I gave in the subsection titles into a file
2. run `make` (on Debian/Ubuntu you may want to install `build-essential`, for other systems consult your documentation)
3. invoke, e.g. with this `env LD_PRELOAD=./mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so ./your_binary`

###### Output (excerpt)

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so ./your_binary
Loaded libcrypto: 0x7f9ad86e3700
        RSA_generate_key == 0x7f9ad8478b50
Calling real_RSA_generate_key(1024, 3, (nil), (nil))
Returned RSA key: 0x55d1bfc40c10 ... I can do what I want with it ... MUHAHAHA!
RSA Private-Key: (1024 bit, 2 primes)
modulus:
    00:d2:85:86:68:fb:1f:b0:92:c7:dd:09:08:7a:39:
    21:7e:74:27:36:08:23:0d:1f:6c:7a:ec:47:5d:fc:
    27:c9:95:c2:a4:e1:9f:99:1b:3f:d9:f8:88:65:30:
    93:c6:7d:2b:31:9b:b1:cb:5c:5a:b8:7a:20:c0:4b:
    63:25:c4:3a:30:c3:81:16:56:28:ac:f7:74:93:6b:
    93:64:db:c9:d5:0f:64:f8:15:b4:0d:18:1d:86:c1:
    60:4b:5a:2f:2f:b7:fb:90:03:13:d5:be:1e:05:05:
    0e:91:54:79:5b:58:2f:02:de:0a:1f:ef:06:a4:0a:
    28:e4:55:3f:31:9d:a9:26:53
publicExponent: 3 (0x3)
privateExponent:
...
```

Explanation:

- Lines 1..2 are from `init()`
- Lines 3..4 are from `RSA_generate_key()` in our wrapper `.so`

  - **NB:** this shows you have full access to all the arguments! While it may be a little more intricate to do, it would also clearly be possible to wrap the callback mechanism provided by OpenSSL into our own, e.g.:

    - prior to calling `real_ RSA_generate_key()`, allocate a struct holding original `callback` pointer and `cb_arg`
    - pass our own callback function

      - inside our callback function unwrap the struct and pass arguments to the original callback if and as needed
    - after `real_ RSA_generate_key()` clean up the allocated struct

The above as Base64-encoded `.tar.xz` file for convenience:

```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```

---

#### Telling `ld.so` to preload the wrapper `.so`

Bash and some other shells will be contend to do it with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so ./your_binary
```

but the more portable way is:

```
env LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so ./your_binary
```

which uses `/usr/bin/env` -- instead of relying on a shell-builtin facility 00 to set the environment variable for a single invocation.

Obviously you could also at the prompt (`$`  signifies it!) to:

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so
$ ./your_binary
```

or on some less comfortable (or older) shells:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so
$ export LD_PRELOAD
$ ./your_binary
```

Last, but not least, you could create a little wrapper script, which we'll name `your_binary.sh` based on `your_binary`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so
exec "${0%.sh}" "$@"
```

- `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is the most portable hashbang, compared to hardcoding the path to a particular `bash` binary
- `export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/mock_openssl_rsagenkey.so` exports `LD_PRELOAD` as environment variable with the shown value
- `exec "${0%.sh}" "$@"`:

  - `"${0%.sh}"` strips the `.sh` suffix, yielding the name without it
  - `"$@"` expanding to the quoted arguments passed to our script (e.g. `"$1" "$2"` ...)
  - `exec` isn't strictly necessary here, but I prefer it for these small wrapper scripts; it replaces the current shell with the given command